# Saving an input value so that if a user leaves blank it reverts back to default

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have tried to create a variable `oldValue` and then if the current value `=== ""` then it will change back to the `oldValue` and because I am using a `for` loop I can explicitly say what the value is.

The code is changing the `div` around the `input` element thats why there is `.parentNode`'s

Can anyone tell me how is it possible to get the value of input and save it, or where I have gone wrong in my code.

```
var inputFocus = function(){
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("inputNoFocus");
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    var input = inputs[i];
    var oldValue = this.value;

    input.addEventListener("focus", function(){

        if(this.value === this.value){
            this.value = "";
        }
        this.parentNode.parentNode.setAttribute("class", "inputFocus");
    }, false);

    input.addEventListener("blur", function(){
        if(this.value === ""){
            this.value = oldValue;
        }
        this.parentNode.parentNode.setAttribute("class", "noHover");
    }, false);
}
}();
```

Comment: `if(this.value === this.value)` What is that doing for you? Always `TRUE`..

Comment: `this.value === this.value`, this will always be true. Shouldn't that be oldValue? (in your focus event)

Comment: I am confused because I need it to check all values that it could be like "Password" or "Username" and if the user changes the value to "" I want it to go back to being its default value or if the user changes it so anything other than "" I want it to stay at the users value...

Comment: Part of your problem is that you do not store `oldValue` in any meaningful way. You need to associate it with the respective `<input>`. The other part of your problem is that you use `this` completely the wrong way.

Comment: @Tomalak yeah I realised this and I have now solved it! Thanks for your help though! http://jsfiddle.net/uEAJ7/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("inputNoFocus");

  function setEmptyVal() {
    if (this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = "";
    this.parentNode.parentNode.setAttribute("class", "inputFocus");
  }

  function setDefaultVal() {
    if (this.value == "") this.value = this.defaultValue;
    this.parentNode.parentNode.setAttribute("class", "noHover");
  }

  for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    var input = inputs[i];

    input.defaultValue = input.value;
    input.addEventListener("focus", setEmptyVal, false);
    input.addEventListener("blur", setDefaultVal, false);
  }
})();
```

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/uEAJ7/).

Comment: @jamcoupe Be sure to take some time to find out how it works.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your trying to do, But from my understanding -- the value from this.value in your functions in the event listeners will be returning `null` -- reason being the scoping in JavaScript. the scope of the value `this.value` will be in the parent function and not the function defined in the eventlisters anonymous function.

Try reading http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting you'll understand the scoping and why or where you might be going wrong.

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot! Got it working now. http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/uEAJ7/